# Qtありでopencvをビルドしたが、テストすると実行時エラーが発生する

Tags: windows, opencv, qt, cmake

以下の環境でビルドしました。

OS: Windows11 64bit
compiler: VS2019
opencv: 4.5.1
Qt: 15.15.1
cmake 3.19.3 with opencv_world checked, withQt checked

cmake、VSのビルド、installを行い、下記のプログラムを実行しました。

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv)
{
cv::Mat src = cv::imread(“baboon.jpg”, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
cv::namedWindow(“image”, cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv::imshow(“image”, src);
cv::waitKey(0);
cv::destroyAllWindows();
return 0;
}
```

実行すると、下記の実行時エラーで終了しました。

```
The procedure entry point … could not be located in the dynamic link library
　?arg@QString@@QEBA?AV1@HVQChar@@@Z C:\Qt\5.15.1\msvc2019_64\bin\Qt5Test.dll
　?qt_metacall@QRadioButton@@UEAAHW4call@@@MetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z C:\opencv\build\x64\vc16\bin\opencv_world451.dll
```

同じことをQtなしで行うと、画像が表示されます。
従って、殆ど間違っていないと思うのですが、Qtを組み込むと何故エラーとなるのかが分かりません。
imshowでボタン付きの新しいGUIを使いたいので、どうしてもQtをバインドしたいです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 版数は微妙に違うようですがこちらの記事が類似の事を扱っていると思われるので参考になるかも。[OpenCV ビルド (V4.5.0)](https://denshikousakusenka.jimdofree.com/%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E6%A7%8B%E7%AF%89/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%96/opencv-%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89/)

Comment: 自己解決しました。

Comment: cmakeでconfig、generateのあとOpenProjectで開いたslnをビルド、インストールしたら、成功しました。これまではbuildフォルダーに作られたslnファイルをVS2019でビルドしていました。

Answer (score 1):

意外なことで自己解決しました。コメントに記しましたが、アドバイスに従い、個別の回答として報告します。
ポイントは、cmakeでgenerateした後のステップでした。generateの後には、buildホルダーにOpenCV.slnが作成されていますが、それをVS2019でビルドすると失敗します。cmakeでgenerateした後、OpenProjectボタンを押してOpenCV.slnを開き、ビルド、インストールすると成功しました。
defaultの設定で、pythonバインドがPython38/Lib/site-packages/cv2に作られます。import cv2するとdllが見つかりませんというエラーが出ましたが、import os、os.add_dll_directory('C:/Qt/5.15.1/msvc2019_64/bin')の後にimport cv2を行うとエラーが消えました。
以上、C++、PythonからQt版opencvを使うことができるようになりました。
何かのお役に立てば幸いです。

Comment: 「cmakeでgenerateした」が質問者さんにしか分からない表現です。具体的なコマンドライン文字列を提示するべきです（質問文に至ってはgenerateしたことすら書かれていませんでしたし）。その手順に問題があったのかもしれませんし。

Comment: cmakeはcmake-guiを用いたので、config、generate、OpenProjectはボタンの名称です。

Answer (score 0):

質問環境がどのように構築されたか書かれておらず、どうアドバイスしたらいいかわからないので、最新のVisual Studioでの操作方法を説明しておきます。

2023/05に公開されたVisual Studio 2022 17.6で[vcpkgと統合されました](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vcpkg-is-now-included-with-visual-studio/)。これを使用すると世界が変わります。

Visual Studio上で普通にC++プロジェクトを作成しますが、プロジェクトのプロパティで**Use Vcpkg Manifest**を`Yes`に設定します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

その後、プロジェクトに`vcpkg.json`を追加し、次の内容を書き込みます。

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/main/docs/vcpkg.schema.json",
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "name": "opencv4",
      "features": ["qt"]
    }
  ]
}
```

これでQtを有効化したOpenCV4が利用できますので、あとはC++ソースコードを普通に記述してビルドするだけです。

Comment: vcpkgのことを教えていただきありがとうございます。cmakeで上手くいかなかった場合の対応策としてトライしたいと思います。